# today.getDate works on other days except on Sunday

Tags: javascript, html

Example of this code that works normally at a specified date, which is a Saturday.

```js
weeks=["Monday","Tuesday","Wednesday","Thursday","Friday","Saturday","Sunday"];
  var today = new Date("September 24, 2022 01:15:00"); 
  document.getElementById("current-day").innerHTML=weeks[today.getDay()-1];
```

```html
<h1 id="current-day"></h1>
```

As stated in my title above, this code works on other days except only on Sundays, it just says Undefined, why is that?

```js
weeks=["Monday","Tuesday","Wednesday","Thursday","Friday","Saturday","Sunday"];
  var today = new Date("September 25, 2022 01:15:00");
  document.getElementById("current-day").innerHTML=weeks[today.getDay()-1];
```

```html
<h1 id="current-day"></h1>
```

Comment: `today.getDay()`returns 0, then you subtract 1 to get -1. There is no index -1 in your array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code logic looks fine but the weeks array should starts with **Sunday** and avoid using **negative 1 with getDay** method.

```js
const weeks = ["Sunday","Monday","Tuesday","Wednesday","Thursday","Friday","Saturday"];
const today = new Date("September 25, 2022 01:15:00");
document.getElementById("current-day").innerHTML = weeks[today.getDay()];
```

```html
<h1 id="current-day"></h1>
```

Comment: Clearly explained my problem and mistake, thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

As it states on [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getDay?retiredLocale=de) for the getDay() function:

> The getDay() method returns the day of the week for the specified date according to local time, where 0 represents Sunday

So if you subtract 1 you end up with a negative number.